# Fantasy Genre Novel with 2 brothers (the sons of Satan), female author?

Tags: novel, story-identification, demons

The question is asking for the title of a novel, however this was also a series of novels.  I remember many details of the plot, but am not certain if those details are from different books in the series or only from the first book. I'm fairly certain the details are spread over the entire series so please bear with me. There are demons, harpies, witches, Satan, undead, etc, who are the focus of the books. Yet this is not a book about religion or morality. These just happen to be the characters. There are normal folk who live in the world, but they are background and are rarely, if ever, mentioned. Here are some details:

- Handsome brother (HB) is tall, dark and known for his exceptional
  sexual prowess.He is apathetic concerning the world at large. He lives for himself.
- Ugly brother (UB) has wings and is not like HB either in looks or personality.
- HB is captured several times by witches who use him as a sexual slave.
- UB is a great warrior and fights for the good of the world.
- Both brothers have extraordinary magical abilities. (They are the sons of Satan after all).
- Satan lives in a castle anyone can visit. He has an office in the basement.
- Satan is raising a daughter of about 13. She is quite precocious and is ultimately the heroine of the entire series.
- The daughter is unconcerned that her father is Satan. He is just her dad.
- Many of the witches or female demons have large power bases and are former wives or lovers of Satan.
- The two brothers have different mothers
- Satan is getting old and ready to retire

This is not urban fantasy. I was reading *The Deed of Parksenarrion* (*TDOP*) by Elizabeth Moon at the time. It was a library book and at the end were several pages of advertisements for other books in the same genre by female authors. I read the synopsis of this book and checked it and the subsequent books out. My assumption is that the female authors advertised at the end of *TDOP* were from the same publisher, Baen Books.

I read all mentioned books between 2007 and 2009. However, *TDOP* was published as an omnibus in 1992. I am not sure of the published date for the book(s) in question. I really want to find out the answer so I can read more by the mystery author.

Thanks for any and all help/suggestions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for the *Black Jewels Trilogy* by Anne Bishop.  The first novel, *Daughter of the Blood*, was published in 1998 and seems to be the one you're thinking of.  The eponymous heroine, Jaenelle, is adopted by Saetan, king of hell.  He has two sons, Daemon (HB) and Lucivar (UB).

Social constructs in this series are... interesting, focusing on the women in power (witches), rather than men, who tend to not hold much power and are relegated in many situations to the status of consort.  The entire series is highly sexualized and very graphic.

Comment: Thank you Adele. As soon as I read the name of the Trilogy it brought it all back. Well done!! One small nit picky correction. The Daughter of the Blood was published in 1998, but the Omnibus was published in 2003. So you get a trillion gold stars instead of a trillion and 1.

Comment: Ah darn.  That single gold star is gonna bother me.  Glad to help. : )