# YA fantasy series with women in power positions

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

This is a series that is a bit graphic for YA but I’m pretty sure it was marketed that way. There are crystals involved in the book- and the title I think. There is a young girl who thinks she is an orphan but realizes she has powers and has to be protected from those who would break her “web” which is her mind basically. Her protector becomes her lover in later books and you find out her dad is Lucifer or something... it is a matriarchy and women keep men as their pleasure slaves.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When (what years) did you read this?  Do you recall any details of the cover(s)?  Check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you remember anything else you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Probably Black Jewels.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: I was recently in a used book store that had _Daughter of the Blood_ from the answer below in the YA section.  I told them they should move it as it is not appropriate--lots of dark stuff in there.

Answer (score 4):

Is it the *Daughter of the Blood* series by Anne Bishop?

Heroine starts as a young girl, magic users have a crystal that indicates the strength of their magic.

Book synopses (copied from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Jewels) which has more details that may be familiar).

> ***Daughter of the Blood***
>
> Seven hundred years ago, a Black Widow witch saw an ancient prophecy come to life in her web of dreams and visions. Now the Dark Realm readies itself for the arrival of its Queen, a Witch who will wield more power than even the High Lord of Hell himself. But she is still young, still open to influence - and corruption.
>
> Whoever controls the Queen controls the darkness. Three men—sworn enemies—know this. And they know the power that hides behind the blue eyes of an innocent young girl. And so begins a ruthless game of politics and intrigue, magic and betrayal, where the weapons are hate and love—and the prize could be terrible beyond imagining.
>
> Jaenelle is destined to rule the Blood, if she can reach adulthood. Saetan, High Lord of Hell and most powerful of the Blood males, becomes Jaenelle's surrogate father and teacher. He cannot protect her outside Hell, where he rules. She refuses to leave Terreille, risking herself to protect or heal other victims of violence. Can Daemon, Saetan's estranged son, keep her safe from the machinations of the evil High Priestess?
>
> ***Heir to the Shadows***
>
> Jaenelle's adoptive father, Saetan, and her foster-family of demons shelter her. To restore her memory and emotional balance, they move to Kaeleer, where Jaenelle gathers a circle of young Queens. She also heals Lucivar, Daemon's half-brother, who offers a brother's love and a warrior's fealty. As she recovers strength and memory, Jaenelle resolves to restore Daemon and cleanse Terreille. She claims her place as Queen of Ebon Askavi and secures Kaeleer from the growing threat of Tereille and the corruption that exists there.
>
> ***Queen of the Darkness***
>
> Jaenelle Angelline now reigns as Queen-protector of the Shadow Realm. No longer will the corrupt Blood slaughter her people and defile her lands. But where one chapter ends, a final, unseen battle remains to be written, and Jaenelle must unleash the terrible power that is Witch to destroy her enemies once and for all.
>
> Even so, she cannot stand alone. Somewhere, long lost in madness, is Daemon, her promised Consort. Only his unyielding love can complete her Court and secure her reign. Yet, even together, their strength may not be enough to hold back the most malevolent of forces.

Comment: If this answer is correct, this question will likely be marked as a duplicate of [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90538/what-is-the-tilte-of-fantasy-genre-novel-with-2-brothers-the-sons-of-satan-fe/90544#90544).  This is mainly a mechanism on this site to link related questions about the same book.